# Powershell select-string match first instance in file and output filename

Tags: powershell, select-string

I have a number of Log files that are generated by an IMAPSync process. There is a Log file per mailbox that has been synced.

I need to identify all the log files that have a specific string.

Currently I have

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt | select-string 'Quota exceeded'
```

This dutifully prints out all the lines that contain this string, which can appear multiple times in a log file. What I'm after for the script to 'stop' when it hits the first match and go onto the next item and print only the filename.

E.g. if I have 3 files:

```
Fu.txt 



Bar.txt



Baz.txt
```

Each has 10,000 lines, and in Bar.txt 3,000 of those have 'Quota Exceeded' - all I want from the script is to output:

```
Bar.txt
```

as opposed to currently, I have a shell window filled with results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be more efficient to use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) with the `-File` parameter instead of `Select-String`, for example, below will output the file's absolute path if the wildcard pattern **was matched once** and then continue with the next file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -PipelineVariable dir | ForEach-Object {
    switch -Wildcard -File ($_.FullName) {
        '*Quota exceeded*' { return $dir.FullName }
    }
}
```

Using the `-List` parameter for `Select-String` might also be a good possibility however I'm inclined towards the above example.

> `-List`

Only the first instance of matching text is returned from each input file. This is the most efficient way to retrieve a list of files that have contents matching the regular expression.

```
(Select-String -Path *.txt -SimpleMatch -List -Pattern 'Quota exceeded').Path
```

Comment: @TheDemonLord I added an optimized example using `Select-String` in case you're interested